# javascript module exports pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

can someone please explain what's the exports variable for:

copied from backbone.js, I also noticed spine.js uses the same pattern.

https://gist.github.com/1375748

```
var Backbone;
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Backbone = exports;
} else {
    Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
}
```

Comment: Need more code. Please post it instead of asking us to look elsewhere for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That module pattern is part of the [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) specification called [CommonJS Modules](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/):

> In a module, there is a free variable called "exports", that is an
>   object that the module may add its API to as it executes.

So basically adding to the exports object defines the API your module exposes.