# What is exports object for?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the first few lines of backbone.js, I don't see why they are testing for undefined on exports or require

It seems obvious that it would be undefined as they did not set it.  If it was a global(window) object then they would have said it explicitly.

```
root.exports  // they don't do this
root.require
```

Why do they check this?

```
typeof exports !== 'undefined'
```

and this

```
if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined'))
```

and this from above

```
!_
```

**Full Snippet**

```
(function(){
    var root = this, 
        previousBackbone = root.Backbone,
        slice = Array.prototype.slice,      
        splice = Array.prototype.splice,
        _ = root._,
        Backbone;
    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        Backbone = exports;
    } else {
        Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
    }
    Backbone.VERSION = '0.9.2';
    if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) {
        _ = require('underscore');
    }
```

Comment: exports is a node.js global variable for exposing public methods in the creation of modules. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html . Backbone.js appears to be one of these modules.

Comment: o.k...why didn't they use root.exports...this is an optimization to shorten the lookup chain.

Comment: I think that this has been answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178535/javascript-module-exports-pattern

Comment: no it hasn't exactly...the issue is that they don't user root...to communicate to the reader that this is a global.

Comment: Maybe because "root" is not defined in browsers global "window" and would throw, as this check is an environment check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's there to allow `Backbone.js` to be used as a `Common.js` module I believe.  More details here: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1

Specifically this bit:

> > > In a module, there is a free variable called "exports", that is an object that the module may add its API to as it executes.

Also, this bit covers your question about `require`:

> > > In a module, there is a free variable "require", that is a Function.  The "require" function accepts a module identifier.  "require" returns the exported API of the foreign module.

Comment: but why don't they use root.exports...that would quicken the lookup chain...more importantly it would make it obvious that it is a global.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I can't really answer that with any certainty - maybe they just didn't think of that?  Or maybe the `root` variable was added in later, and they didn't think to change that bit?  I'm just guessing really...

Comment: and they don't have any 'hard dependencies' except require.js......common.js it optional....just fyi.